# Android uiautomator: how to get EditText field by index?

Tags: android, testing, automation, android-uiautomator

The UiSelector allow you to get the EditText field by text, textStartsWith, contains etc:

```
   UiObject obj = new UiObject(new UiSelector().text(text));
```

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/uiautomator/UiSelector.html

However how to get the 2nd text field? It happens that field does not have any text or description. If I just do

```
   UiObject textField = new UiObject(new UiSelector().index(index));
```

Then it returns me a field that is not a EditText with the index.

Thanks!

Comment: If you know the resourceId you can use that to select the text field.
[UiSelector#resourceId](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/uiautomator/UiSelector.html#resourceId(java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
UiObject textField = new UiObject(new UiSelector()
   .className("android.widget.EditText").instance(1)
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried it before. The problem is it does not search for the whole screen. i.e., if the EditText is 3 levels down in the UI hierarchy, then the call  UiObject textField = new UiObject(new UiSelector()
   .className("android.widget.EditText").instance(2) will cause exception:    Error in testSearch:
com.android.uiautomator.core.UiObjectNotFoundException: UiSelector[CLASS=android.widget.EditText, INSTANCE=1]
 at com.android.uiautomator.core.UiObject.getText(UiObject.java:481)
 at com.magnet.mobileserver.tests.android.ui.app.TemplateApp.testSearch(TemplateApp.java:44)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this -

```
 UiSelector(). className("android.widget.ImageView") .enabled(true). instance(1). setText("Hola!");
```

or

```
 UiObject editText = new UiObject(new UiSelector(). className("android.widget.EditText"));
 editText.setText("Hola!");
```